# gvisSankey titles of the axes are not appearing when using options=list(vAxes="[{title:'val1'}, {title:'val2'}]")

Tags: googlevis

I am trying to draw a sankey diagram with gvisSankey. All the options i put under options=list .. are working well except for the axes titles (vaxes). As in i see the diagram and colors choses except the names of the axes.

Anyone has a solution for this?

thanks
M

```
 f <- gvisSankey(data,from="val1",to="val1",weight="weight",
                 options=list(vAxes="[{title:'val1'}, {title:'val2'}]"))
 plot(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

One answer I could think of is that the "vAxes" argument isn't an R-argument and you have to specify it in JavaScript (JS) style. Something like

```
options = list(sankey = "{vAxes = '[{title:'val1'}, {title:'val2'}]'))}")
```

This way the options that are specifically made for JS are read in via JS.

Comment: What you have for the axes is correct, but your "to" variable, shouldn't that be equal to "val2" and **not** "val1"?